# Is the caption package not compatible with xltabular?

Tags: captions, xltabular

I am using `xltabular` in order to use `tabularx` with multi-page tables.  I looked at the various options and this one seemed to be the most recent and the one I could get to work.

However, I cannot get custom captions to work with it.  Here's a MWE.  This compiles, but as soon as I uncomment the `\captionsetup` command, it no longer compiles.  Anyone know a fix for this?

I have tried:

1. Putting `[longtable]` as the type in `\captionsetup` (since in theory `xltabular` does load `longtable`).
2. Moving the `\label` to the bottom but that makes `xltabular` upset because for some reason `xltabular` ONLY works with the label inside the caption brackets.
3. Tried loading `tabularx` before and after `xltabular` (probably unnecessary, and didn't help). In fact, I rearranged the order of all the packages a few times... even doing caption and the options first doesn't work.

Anyone know a fix for this? I have a lot of captions and would rather be able to change it ONCE in the preamble rather than have to change every single caption....

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{mysep}{:\\}
% \captionsetup {  font            ={small,sc,onehalfspacing},
%                   labelfont       ={bf,sc},
%                   labelsep        =newline,
%                   tableposition   =top,
%                   skip            =5pt}

\begin{document}
% Table
%
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}%


\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ L{0.1} L{0.15} L{2.8}  L{0.95} }
    \caption{Blah blah blah. \label{tab:blah}}\\
    \hline\hline \multicolumn{2}{c}{Ref}&Focus&Approach\\\hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{\dots Continued}\\
    \hline\hline \multicolumn{2}{c}{Ref}&Focus&Approach\\\hline
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{\dots Continued}\\
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot
    B & Blah         & Words Words Words    & More Words    \\
    B & Blah         & Words Words Words    & More words    \\
    \hline\hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Edit to ask two follow ups:

This MWE also works correctly in my test document, but for some unknown reason makes the first heading typeset in italics...that just mystifies me.

Second: In my actual document the first version of the table typesets the double `\hline` correctly.  But in THIS version of the table (which isn't that different) it typesets the two `\hline`s on top of each other.

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{$}#1<{$}}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ M{C{0.25}} L{1.75} }
    \caption{Sets used in ($\mathcal{M}$).\label{tab:set} }\\
    \hline\hline
    Symbol   & Description \\ \hline 
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\dots Continued}\\ 
    \hline\hline
    Symbol   & Description \\ \hline 
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{Continued\dots}
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot
    \mathcal{A}          & blah, $a$ \\
    \mathcal{D}          & blah, $d$ \\
    \hline\hline
\end{xltabular}
```

MWE with all of my ridiculous short cuts!  Some of my equations get REALLY long if I don't use short cuts. :-(  Basically unreadable without them.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{mysep}{:\\}
\captionsetup {  font            ={small,sc,onehalfspacing},
                  labelfont       ={bf,sc},
                  labelsep        =mysep,
                  tableposition   =top,
                  skip            =5pt}


\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}%    
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{$}#1<{$}}
\newcommand{\bfsc}  [1] {\textbf{\sc{#1}}}  % Consistent table heading format
\newcommand{\mc}    [1] {\mathcal{#1}}
\newcommand{\cmctr}[3]
    {\rowcolor{#1}\multicolumn{#2}{c}{\sc{#3}} \\ \hline}
\newcommand{\lp}    {\left(}
\newcommand{\rp}    {\right)}
\newcommand{\aij}   {\lp i,j \rp}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ M{C{0.25}} L{1.75} }
    \caption{Sets used in ($\mc{M}$). \label{tab:set} }\\
    \hline\hline
    \bfsc{Symbol}   & \bfsc{Description} \\ \hline 
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\dots Continued}\\ 
    \hline\hline
    \bfsc{Symbol}   & \bfsc{Description} \\ \hline 
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{Continued\dots}
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot
    \cmctr{gray!30}{2}{Sets}
    \mc{A}          & blah, $\aij$ \\
    \mc{D}          & blah, $d$ \\
    \hline\hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Results]

Comment: Well the error message is quite clear: `! Package caption Error: Option onehalfspacing requires the setspace package`. So add `\usepackage{setspace}`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very simple fix: load `setspace` when you want to use `\onehalfspacing`. I took the opportunity to replace the `\hline`s with the rules from `booktabs`, which add some vertical padding to the rules, and have variable thicknesses.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{mysep}{:\\}
 \captionsetup { font ={small, sc, onehalfspacing},%
 labelfont ={bf,sc},
 labelsep =mysep, %newline,
 tableposition =top,
 skip =5pt}

\begin{document}
% Table
%
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}%

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ L{0.1} L{0.15} L{2.8} L{0.95} }
    \caption{Blah blah blah. And some more text to see if onehalfspacing works in a caption \label{tab:blah}}\\
    \toprule\midrule \multicolumn{2}{c}{Ref}&Focus&Approach\\\midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{\dots Continued}\\
      \toprule\midrule \multicolumn{2}{c}{Ref}&Focus&Approach\\\hline
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{\dots Continued}\\
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot
    B & Blah & Words Words Words & More Words \\
    B & Blah & Words Words Words & More words \\
    \midrule\midrule
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did not catch that because \usepackage{setspace} was actually loaded in the full document.  Which reminds me that I didn't even start to come up with this MWE for that issue, it was another one!  I made the MWE by stripping out most of the table formatting because in my main document a similar table (with different column definitions) is putting the two \hline commanbds on top of each other (basically making a bold line) instead of spacing them apart.  When I use this MWE in my test document, it looks fine.  But in the main document, it doubles the lines up:

Comment: oops...I will add the other code up there....

Comment: Okay, "follow up" questions posted below original post.  The \hline typesetting on top of each other was the original reason I started a test case....

Comment: And....using toprule and midrule somehow fixes my \hline\hline problem though I have NO IDEA why when \hline \hline works earlier in the document.  It's go to be user error (computers only do what you tell them) but for the life of me I cannot figure out what is that different about the second table!

Comment: It is hard to help without knowing what the personal commands do,  in your edit. Try  to post a minimal and compilable  code  that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Done!  I just kept putting formatting back in until it reappeared.

Comment: And that shaded row is one of the reasons I was using \hline.  \midrule leaves space that isn't shaded....

Comment: Yes, I know. In this you can have  some vertical padding for lines  using the `cellspace` package,  and variable thickness lines with either the `boldline` package, or using the `\Xhline` and `\Xcline`commands from `makecell`.

Comment: Any idea why it puts the two \hline commands on top of each other though?

Comment: I don't  know the details, but something like  `\hline\noalign{\vskip 2pt}\hline` should work.