# How to use captionsetup with xltabular?

Tags: captions, longtable, xltabular

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526353/is-the-caption-package-not-compatible-with-xltabular) question seems to be the same, but I didn't find the answer there.

I have problem with using `xltabular` and `captionsetup` in one document.

In this MWE everything works perfect until I use `xltabular`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\continuetablecaption}{%
    \captionsetup{name=\textit{Continue of table},font=it}
    \caption{}
}%


\begin{document}



\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}

    \caption{Animal table}\\
    \hline
    animal & weight &  length \\ \hline
    \endfirsthead

    \continuetablecaption\\
    \hline
    animal & weight &  length \\ \hline
    \endhead

elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I tried to put `\usepackage{xltabular}` in every place in preamble, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does not work, precisely?

Comment: @Bernard If I uncomment `\usepackage{xltabular}` I wiil get an error: Undefined control sequence. \continuetablecaption

Comment: @Bernard try it out. It is quite obvious what doesn't work.

Comment: I don't get it, it compiles just fine for me either way. (Edit: Loading `xtabular` after `caption` seems to produce the error, but the MWE is fine)

Answer (score 1):

You may consider to use `tabularray` package. Styles of your table captions can be relative simple defined by `TblrTemplate`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{nc}{% definitions for continue caption style
  \par\centering
    \DefTblrTemplate {conthead-text}{nc}{Continue of table}
    \UseTblrTemplate {conthead-text}{nc}
  \par
}
\NewTblrTheme{scc}{% captions styles
    \SetTblrTemplate{capcont}{nc}%
    \SetTblrStyle{conthead-text}{font=\small}
    \SetTblrStyle{contfoot-text}{font=\footnotesize\itshape}
%
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-text}{font=\small}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\small\bfseries}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[theme = scc,
caption = {Animal table},
  label = {tab:animal}
                    ]{hline{3-Y}, vlines,
                     colspec = {l cc},
                      row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
                     rowhead = 1
                     }
% Headline
    \toprule
animal  & weight &  length   \\
    \midrule
        % table content column by column, row by row
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
%\end{longtblr}
%\end{document}
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

You may consider default settings for `longtblr`. I. this case the preambles of document and table are

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Animal table},
  label = {tab:animal}
                    ]{hline{3-Y}, vlines,
                     colspec = {l cc},
                      colsep = 9pt,
                      row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
                     rowhead = 1
                     }
% Headline
```

which produce more usual tale captions at each table parts:

[image]

**Note:**
use of `xltabular` package assume that at least one table's column is of `X` type. Unfortunately, your MWE doesn't reflect this, so it is unknow, how columns should be formatted. For example, you may write column specification as `colspec = {X[l] X[c] X[c]}` and get the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in order to give you an idea how to easily work with `xltabular`, I set up the following MWE with the data given in your post.

You do not need a special caption setup for the "running title", i.e. which text appears on the next page. Instead use the area between `\endfirsthead` and `\endhead` for that. In my example this is the table ID and the text "continued from previous page".

What I also saw in your code, is that you did not import `booktabs`. In fact, this is a hard dependency which needs to be imported explicitly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|c|c|c|}
    \caption{Animal table} \\ % This line break is needed, otherwise timeout in compilation
    
     % Headline
        \toprule
        animal & weight &  length \\ \hline
        \endfirsthead 
       
        \multicolumn{3}{c}%
        {{\textbf{\tablename} \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
        \toprule
        animal & weight &  length \\ \hline 
        \endhead
        
        \multicolumn{3}{r}{{\textit{Continued on next page}}}  \\ 
        \endfoot
        
        \bottomrule  % the really end of the table
        \endlastfoot

        % table content column by column, row by row
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline
elephant & 5 t & 3 m \\ \hline

\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```